# Can't set small thumb in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

How to change the **indicator thumb size** of a horizontal scrollview? [just like a small circle in progressbaar]
I have tried using a drawable with smaller width. But it still covers almost 70% of the Scrollview!

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/thumb">
```

Here drawable/thumb is just a 5x5 image.

Still this produce a long indicator!
[image]

like this small one[image]

Comment: its size detemined by the width of the horizontalscrollview's child that means if the child is more than it gets automatically decreased.If you dont follow this then user can misguide..got my point?

Comment: I don't want to shrink the scrollbar size, i want a smaller thumb/indicator.

Comment: you still didnt get my point.. do you? this scrollbar size is depend upon the size of their child if the number of child is small then the scrollbar size is big and viceversa..

Comment: @KailashDabhi I want a smaller thumb just like a small rectangle even if the child size are larger. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@android:color/darker_gray">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I did the same, didn't I?

Comment: if you incress "scrollbarSize" then ScrollBar Scroll Size will be incress and if you decress "scrollbarSize" then ScrollBar Scroll Size will be decress....

Comment: I don't want to change the scrollview size, i want a smaller thumb!